Converting LaTeX expression to PNG files
Currently, my partner and i are compiling a function to convert LaTeX mathematical expressions to PNG files, using Python as the programming language and XeLaTeX as the LaTeX compiler. Here is my code.There are some letters  that are written in my mother-tongue so that's why it seems strange):
from sympy import *
import random
import os
import subprocess
#import pdf2image
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
import cv2
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed
import pdfplumber
import pymupdf
import wand
from wand.image import Image
#PRACTICE MODE:

#1.TOPIC: TRIGONOMETRY
#Question type 1: Theory
#LaTeX-\>self-compiled function has corresponding PDF

def compile_latex(file_path):
    os.chdir(os.path.dirname(file_path))
    try:
        subprocess.run(\['xelatex', file_path\], check=True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print("Error compiling LaTeX file", e)
        exit(1)
    pdf_file_path = file_path.replace('.tex', '.pdf')
    if not os.path.exists(pdf_file_path):
        print("PDF file was not created")
        exit(1)
    return pdf_file_path


def convert_pdf_to_png(pdf_file_path):
    png_file_path = pdf_file_path.replace('.pdf', '.png')
    try:
        with Image(filename=pdf_file_path, resolution=240) as img:
            img.compression_quality = 80
            img.save(filename=png_file_path)
            print("PDF successfully converted into PNG:", png_file_path)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error converting PDF to PNG: ", e)
    return png_file_path


def convert_multiple_pdf_to_png(pdf_files):
    results=[]
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        futures={executor.submit(convert_pdf_to_png,pdf_file): pdf_file for pdf_file in pdf_files}
        for future in as_completed(futures):
            result=future.result()
            results.append(result)
    return results


#Note!: This is the function I wrote myself to compile individual image files. Please read the operating principle.

def MakeFile(phuongan,modauchofilelatex,endtext,count):
#Set variable b, which plays a key role in identifying which is the question file and which are the 4 corresponding answer files. Thanks to it, we can compile successfully and as desired
#READ the conditions CAREFULLY to help the machine know when to print the question file and when to print 4 corresponding answer files.
    b=0


    folder="C:/Users/HP/Downloads/001_QO_folder"
    #pdf_files=[os.path.join(folder,file) for file in os.listdir(folder) if file.endswith('.pdf')]
    for i in range(len(phuongan)):
        if(b==0):

            #Create a ques file, set the count variable to type the question status, because after each print of 5 files containing questions and 4 answers, I will increase count+1.
            file_path= "C:/Users/HP/Downloads/001_QO_folder/001_Q0_%s_QUES.tex"%str(count)
            #pdf_file_path=os.path.abspath(file_path.replace('.tex','.pdf'))
            #png_file_path=os.path.abspath(file_path.replace('.tex','.png'))
            file=open("C:/Users/HP/Downloads/001_QO_folder/001_Q0_%s_QUES.tex"%str(count),'w',encoding='utf-8')
            file.write(modauchofilelatex+phuongan[0]+endtext)
            file.close()
            pdf_file_path=os.path.abspath(file_path.replace('.tex','.pdf'))
            #dvi_file_path=file_path.replace('.tex','.dvi')
            #xdv_file_path=file_path.replace('.tex','.xdv')
            compile_latex(file_path)
            #Convert pdf to image
            #image=convert_from_path(pdf_file_path)
            #Save as png format
            #image[0].save(png_file_path,'PNG')
            #Delete redundant files through their paths
            convert_pdf_to_png(pdf_file_path)
            #os.remove(file_path)
            #os.remove(pdf_file_path)
            #Each time the question is printed, the b's variable number will increase from 0 to 1 -> the score is not satisfied -> from there it can be identified when printing out 4 answers.
            b=b+1
        else:
            file_ans=open("C:/Users/HP/Downloads/001_QO_folder/001_Q0_%s_ANS%s.tex"%(str(count),str(i)),'w', encoding='utf-8')
            file_ans.write(modauchofilelatex+phuongan[i]+endtext)
            file_ans.close()
            file_ans_path = "C:/Users/HP/Downloads/001_QO_folder/001_Q0_%s_ANS%s.tex"%(str(count),str(i))
            pdf_file_ans_path=file_ans_path.replace('.tex','.pdf')
            png_file_ans_path=file_ans_path.replace('.tex','.png')
            #dvi_file_ans_path=file_ans_path.replace('.tex','.dvi')
            #xdv_file_ans_path=file_ans_path.replace('.tex','.xdv')
            compile_latex(file_ans_path)
            #imageans=convert_from_path(pdf_file_ans_path)
            #imageans[0].save(png_file_ans_path,'PNG')
            convert_from_path(pdf_file_ans_path)
            #os.remove(file_ans_path)
            #os.remove(pdf_file_ans_path)

            #results= convert_multiple_pdf_to_png(pdf_files)
            #for result in results:
            #print(result)

I tried running it several times. The code did turn PDFs to PNGs as I expected, because that's the only way I can think about. But the thing it printed out was the whole page. This was the thing I expected  but I was unable to do that. In conclusion, is there any way to solve this problem?

I tried to fixed the indentation of your code but I am not 100% that my edit is fully faithful to the original one. Please give it a look and try in future to post readable code & post just minimal working example

By the way is not quite cleat what you want to do. Do you want to translate a LaTeX string into a rendered image? In that case there is easy solution

Maybe have a look at pdfCropMargins  : "The pdfCropMargins program is a command-line application to automatically crop the margins of PDF files." But it can also works in python, as per their documentation example below. You may need to tweek function parameters though.
from pdfCropMargins import crop
crop(["-p", "20", "-u", "-s", "paper1.pdf"])
crop(["-p", "0", "-gui", "paper2.pdf"])

Exemple from their doc :


Thanks. Fortunately, i have solved my problem kinda. However, i also realize that the compile time of this program is quite long, so i wonder if there is a way to reduce the time and help the program runs faster with this LaTeX-to-PNG function. I'm extremely grateful to anyone who can solve this.
